# No Data Available Datatables

Tags: jquery, vue.js, asynchronous, datatable, async-await

I was trying to get data using the axios and then show the result into a datatable (jQuery) in vue. Its showing no data available.
script

```
 async mounted(){
     axios.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/new.json")
     .then( (res) => { 
        this.tableData =  res.data.data.children;
        console.log(this.tableData);
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.myDataTable').DataTable();
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does console.log(res) returns?

Comment: @Catmal Hey, It returns the json data from the link above

Comment: There's no link above..

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
async mounted(){
 axios.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/new.json")
 .then( (res) => { 
    this.tableData =  res.data.data.children;
    console.log(this.tableData);
    $('.myDataTable').DataTable();
});
```

The problem is that you use $(document).ready() when the document is already loaded. So this part won't be executed.

Comment: It shows the same result even when I do not use $(document).ready()